# How to write to database synchronously?

Tags: .net, database

How controller's actions write to database synchronously? I tried RowVersion but it ignores excepted write.

**Update**

Let say I have a blogspost. When visitors access to a post, I want to increase the post's view stat.

I tried RowVersion to handle concurrent accesses.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> View(string postTitleSlug)
{
    var post = await _db.Posts
        .Where(p => p.TitleSlug.Equals(postTitleSlug)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var saveFailed = true;
    while (saveFailed)
    {
        try
        {
            saveFailed = false;

            post.ViewCount += 1;
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            saveFailed = true;

            e.Entries.Single().Reload();
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

But I can not handle its behavior. If two or more tables involved, the `while` loop too much.

Because these kind of stats are not necessary be updated immediately, so I'm thinking about task queues like rabbitmq, resque... But is it overkill for my simple blogspost?

Comment: Can you expand on your question and add sample code. As is it's difficult to understand what you're asking

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: I"m not sure what problem you're having. Whats the problem with just incrementing the count? Are you worried that two simultaneous visits will only increment once?

Comment: Yes. I'm worrying that two simultaneous visits will only increment once